# php script select where statement xcode

Tags: php, mysql, xcode

I'm developing an app with xcode and trying to do a select with some statement, but the query is not working. For example, I created a button in app that contains letter 'A', when I click it calls a script php (JSON) that does a select and return in a listview some result that starts with 'A'.

In xcode I try to define an api like this: `#define GET_API @"http://website.16mb.com/field/testsearch.php"` or this `@"http://website.16mb.com/field/testsearch.php?letter=%@,letter"`

In my testsearch.php I wrote:

```
<?php

    $host = "mysql.xxxx.com";
    $user = "userxxx";
    $pass = "xxxxx";
    $database = "udatabase";

    mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die("Error connection");

    mysql_select_db($database) or die("Error to select database");

   $letter = $_GET["letter"];
   $query = "SELECT * FROM tablename where letter = '$letter' ORDER BY letter DESC";

    $result =  mysql_query($query) or die ("Error ");
    mysql_close();
    $lines = array();
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $lines[] = $r;

    }
    echo json_encode($linhas);    

?>
```

Someone could tell me how I send a data from xcode to script with select and statement? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$letter = $_GET['letter'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `tablename` where `letter` = '".$letter."' ORDER BY letter DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$lines = array();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$lines[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($lines);    

?>
```

try this

Comment: Finally I did it. My API I defined @"http://website.16mb.com/field/testsearch.php?letra=%@",letra] and the php script I did what you wrote.. thanks for the help!